# i cant update profile in node.js

Tags: node.js, asp.net, json, web

"ERROR'

ValidationError: 2 errors occurred
at finishTestRun (C:\Users\daryl\Documents\Full_stack_code\practical_06_solution\learning-app\server\node_modules\yup\lib\util\runTests.js:63:20)
at C:\Users\daryl\Documents\Full_stack_code\practical_06_solution\learning-app\server\node_modules\yup\lib\util\runTests.js:17:5
at finishTestRun (C:\Users\daryl\Documents\Full_stack_code\practical_06_solution\learning-app\server\node_modules\yup\lib\util\runTests.js:63:11)
at C:\Users\daryl\Documents\Full_stack_code\practical_06_solution\learning-app\server\node_modules\yup\lib\util\createValidation.js:72:104
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
value: {},
path: undefined,
type: undefined,
errors: [ 'name is a required field', 'email is a required field' ],
params: undefined,
inner: [
ValidationError: name is a required field
at createError (C:\Users\daryl\Documents\Full_stack_code\practical_06_solution\learning-app\server\node_modules\yup\lib\util\createValidation.js:54:21)
at C:\Users\daryl\Documents\Full_stack_code\practical_06_solution\learning-app\server\node_modules\yup\lib\util\createValidation.js:72:107
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
value: undefined,
path: 'name',
type: 'required',
errors: [Array],
params: [Object],
inner: []
},
ValidationError: email is a required field
at createError (C:\Users\daryl\Documents\Full_stack_code\practical_06_solution\learning-app\server\node_modules\yup\lib\util\createValidation.js:54:21)
at C:\Users\daryl\Documents\Full_stack_code\practical_06_solution\learning-app\server\node_modules\yup\lib\util\createValidation.js:72:107
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
value: undefined,
path: 'email',
type: 'required',
errors: [Array],
params: [Object],
inner: []
}
]
}

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
    Box,
    Typography,
    TextField,
    Button,
    Grid,
    List,
    ListItem,
    ListItemText,
    ListItemIcon,
    Divider,
} from '@mui/material';
import http from '../http';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import PermIdentityIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PermIdentity';

function Profiles() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) {
            http
                .get('/user/auth')
                .then((res) => {

                    setUser(res.data.user);
                    // Set the selectedImage to the current profile picture when the component mounts


                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                    // Handle the error
                });
        }
    }, []);


    const profilePicture = user?.image;

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            name: user ? user.name : '',
            email: user ? user.email : '',
            phone: user ? user.phone : '',
            address: user ? user.address : '',
            profilePicture: ' ',
        },
        enableReinitialize: true,
        validationSchema: yup.object().shape({
            name: yup
                .string()
                .trim()
                .min(3, 'Name must be at least 3 characters')
                .max(100, 'Name must be at most 100 characters')
                .required('Name is required'),
            email: yup.string().trim().email('Invalid email').required('Email is required'),
            phone: yup.string().trim().max(20, 'Phone must be at most 20 characters'),
            address: yup.string().trim().max(100, 'Address must be at most 100 characters').nullable(),
            profilePicture: yup.mixed().nullable(),
        }),
        onSubmit: (data) => {
            data.name = data.name.trim();
            data.email = data.email.trim();
            if (data.phone) {
                data.phone = data.phone.trim();
            }
            if (data.address) {
                data.address = data.address.trim();
            }

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name', data.name);
            formData.append('email', data.email);
            formData.append('phone', data.phone);
            formData.append('address', data.address);
            formData.append('profilePicture', data.profilePicture || '');

            http
                .put(`/user/profile/${user.id}`, formData)
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res.data);
                    toast.success('Profile updated successfully!');
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                    toast.error('Error updating profile. Please try again.');
                });
        },
    });

    return (
        <Box sx={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
                    <Box
                        sx={{
                            border: '1px solid black',
                            p: 2,
                            marginTop: '10px',
                            display: 'flex',
                            flexDirection: 'column',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                        }}
                    >
                        {user && (
                            <>
                                <img
                                    src={profilePicture}
                                    alt="Profile"
                                    style={{ width: '200px', height: '200px', borderRadius: '50%' }}
                                />
                                <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                                    {user.name}
                                </Typography>
                            </>
                        )}
                    </Box>
                    <List component="nav" sx={{ border: '1px solid gray', marginTop: '10px' }} disablePadding>
                        <Divider />
                        <ListItem divider>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                <PermIdentityIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary="Account Details" />
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem divider>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                <PermIdentityIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary="Change Password" />
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem divider>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                <PermIdentityIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary="Credit Card Detail" />
                        </ListItem>
                    </List>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
                    <Box sx={{ border: '1px solid black', p: 2, borderRadius: 1 }}>
                        <Typography variant="h5" sx={{ mb: 2 }}>
                            Customer Profile
                        </Typography>
                        <Box component="form" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                            <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center">
                                <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                                    <TextField
                                        fullWidth
                                        margin="normal"
                                        autoComplete="off"
                                        label="Name"
                                        name="name"
                                        value={formik.values.name}
                                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                        error={formik.touched.name && Boolean(formik.errors.name)}
                                        helperText={formik.touched.name && formik.errors.name}
                                    />
                                    <TextField
                                        fullWidth
                                        margin="normal"
                                        autoComplete="off"
                                        label="Email"
                                        name="email"
                                        value={formik.values.email}
                                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                        error={formik.touched.email && Boolean(formik.errors.email)}
                                        helperText={formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email}
                                    />
                                    <TextField
                                        fullWidth
                                        margin="normal"
                                        autoComplete="off"
                                        label="Phone"
                                        name="phone"
                                        value={formik.values.phone}
                                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                        error={formik.touched.phone && Boolean(formik.errors.phone)}
                                        helperText={formik.touched.phone && formik.errors.phone}
                                    />
                                    <TextField
                                        fullWidth
                                        margin="normal"
                                        autoComplete="off"
                                        label="Address"
                                        name="address"
                                        value={formik.values.address}
                                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                        error={formik.touched.address && Boolean(formik.errors.address)}
                                        helperText={formik.touched.address && formik.errors.address}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12} md={6} style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    {selectedImage ? (
                                        // If an image is selected, show the uploaded profile picture
                                        <img
                                            src={URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage)}
                                            alt="Uploaded Profile"
                                            style={{ width: '100px', height: '100px', borderRadius: '50%' }}
                                        />
                                    ) : (
                                        // If no image is selected, show the current profile picture or a default picture
                                        <img
                                            src={profilePicture || "default-profile-picture.jpg"}
                                            alt="Profile"
                                            style={{ width: '100px', height: '100px', borderRadius: '50%' }}
                                        />
                                    )}
                                    {/* Profile picture input to update the picture */}
                                    <input
                                        type="file"
                                        name="profilePicture"
                                        accept="image/*"
                                        onChange={(event) => {
                                            formik.setFieldValue('profilePicture', event.currentTarget.files[0]);
                                            setSelectedImage(event.currentTarget.files[0]);
                                        }}
                                        style={{ display: 'none' }}
                                        id="profilePictureInput"
                                    />
                                    <label htmlFor="profilePictureInput">
                                        <Button component="span">Choose Image</Button>
                                    </label>
                                    {formik.touched.profilePicture && formik.errors.profilePicture && (
                                        <Typography color="error">{formik.errors.profilePicture}</Typography>
                                    )}
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <Button variant="contained" type="submit">
                                UPDATE
                            </Button>
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Box>
    );
}

Profiles.propTypes = {
    // Add any prop types if needed
};

export default Profiles;
```

i receive this two errors but i don't understand why I will get this error suddenly
i want it to update this profile prefectly

Answer (score 0):

The validation error indicating that the name and email fields are not being provided when you submit the form.
There could be a timing issue related to the useEffect hook, which fetches the user data. Formik form initialization might be happening before the user data is available, causing the form fields to be empty and leading to the validation errors. In your case it looks like formik reinitialization is not happening when the user data has been fetched. There are different approaches you can take to make sure formik reinitialization.
I suggest you lookinto it to find the best approach to fit your case. Having a separate useEffect to trigger formik reinitialization should technically work too. Something like this

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
        formik.setValues({
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            phone: user.phone,
            address: user.address,
            profilePicture: '',
        });
    }
}, [user])
```